# Positive lookbehind regex not matching as expected

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a positive lookbehind in python regex to match device names and serial numbers in this sample `zpool` output.  I think I'm not quite understanding something about the lookbehind syntax because I'm not able to match the serial numbers.

I'm using the Patterns app on my desktop to sandbox this.  I have several other StackOverflow questions about lookbehind assertions, but what I can find just seems to suggest I'm on the right track, and nothing I've seen so far has made it clear what I'm getting wrong.

```
pool                           ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz2-0                       ONLINE       0     0     0
    diskid/DISK-PK2331PAG6ZLMT   ONLINE       0     0     0 
    da21                         ONLINE       0     0     0 
    diskid/DISK-PK2331PAG6ZVMT   ONLINE       0     0     0 
    diskid/DISK-PK2331PAG728ET   ONLINE       0     0     0 
    diskid/DISK-PK2331PAG6YGXT   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I want to grab the device or serial number in the first group, and its status (ONLINE|AVAIL) in the second group. The regex I'm using is:

`^\s+(da\d+|(?<=diskid/DISK-)\S+)\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\s`

It's matching the device name `da21` and its status, but it's not seeing the devices named by serial number.  What am I missing about this syntax?

Comment: It's because the lookebind is looking at the location after `^\s+` (where that text obviously doesn't exist). Try `(da\d+|(?<=diskid/DISK-)\S+)\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\b` or `^\s+(?:diskid/DISK-(\S+)|da(\d+))\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\b`

Comment: You may only solve it as you want with PyPi regex module.

Comment: @ctwheels: I'm not sure what you mean.  `^\s+diskid/DISK-` would match.. the text does exist after `^\s+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you expand on that? Why wouldn't the stdlib `re` module work here?  I'm writing this based on stdlib documentation.

Comment: Because the pattern you want is `((?<=^\s+)da\d+|(?<=^\s+diskid/DISK-)\S+)\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\s`, see [JS demo](https://regex101.com/r/as6ZJe/1) in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it's not working

Let's look at a single line to see what your regex is matching:

```
# your regex
^\s+(da\d+|(?<=diskid/DISK-)\S+)\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\s

# your string
    diskid/DISK-PK2331PAG6ZLMT   ONLINE       0     0     0
<                     # ^ assert position at start of string
^^^^                  # \s+ match one or more whitespace characters
    ^!                # da\d+ matches d, fails to match a, backtrack; try next alternation
<<<<<!                # (?<=diskid/DISK-) assert what precedes matches the lookbehind
# This fails because the text to the left of the position that the parser is at does
#     not match diskid/DISK- (it's four spaces as was previously matched by \s+)
```

---

### How to fix it?

There are multiple regex patterns that may satisfy what you're trying to accomplish:

#### Option 1: Single capture group

This captures `\S+` if it's preceded by `diskid/DISK-`, or `da\d+` into capture group 1, then captures `ONLINE` or `AVAIL` into capture group 2.

```
((?<=diskid/DISK-)\S+|da\d+)\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\b
```

Pro: One capture group
Con: It can't ensure that the first capture group is at the start of the line

#### Option 2: Anchored to the start of the line

This captures `\S+` into capture group 1 if it's preceded by `diskid/DISK-`, or `da\d+` into capture group 2, then captures `ONLINE` or `AVAIL` into capture group 3.

```
^\s+(?:diskid/DISK-(\S+)|(da\d+))\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\b
```

Pro: Anchored to start of line - we can ensure that's where the data is that we're trying to match (`^\s+`)
Con: Two capture groups (we can't match two different sets of data with two different sets of conditions for prepended strings into one capture group)

#### Option 3: use `regex` library

We can accomplish it using `PyPi regex` library quite easily yielding us one group and asserting its position in the string.

Branch reset method (the alternation yields a single capture group instead of two):

```
^\s+(?|diskid/DISK-(\S+)|(da\d+))\s+(ONLINE|AVAIL)\b
      ^           # same as option 2, but uses branch reset
```

Comment: Thanks!  I _think_ I understand what's going on in the parser now.  The lookbehind is doing something slightly different from what I expected.